# Mule XML Streaming - (Mule xmltoxmltransformation)

Tags: mule

Trying to use the Mule XML streaming feature as have to process very large xml files. Followed the documentation, the document does not have concrete examples.

When I inspected the payload I get the XMLUtils class and not the XMLStreamReader class as stated in the documentation.

The flow is as follows have a file connector which passes payload to a custom transformer, the transformer passes the data to a spring bean which is going to have event based processing.

In the spring bean. At run time the spring bean gets the XMLUtils class and not the XMLStreamReader class.

Mule - Config:

```
<spring:beans>
   <spring:bean id="OracleCDMMapper" class="oraclecdmstream.OracleCDMMapper"> 
</spring:bean>
<spring:bean id = "OraclePaySlip" class="com.nect.transform.OracleCDMPaySlip" ></spring:bean>

</spring:beans>

<flow name="mulefileconnectorexampleFlow1" >
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:/c-OracleCloud/src/main/resources" pollingFrequency="600000" moveToDirectory="C:/c-OracleCloud/src/main/resources/back"  doc:name="File Input" >
           <!--  <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="(^*.xml$)" caseSensitive="false"/>
 -->            <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.xml"></file:filename-wildcard-filter>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="Transferring file : #[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger message ="Logger 1 "  level="INFO" doc:name ="Logger1" />
        <!--  Call the XMLSTREAMER  -->
       **<custom-transformer name="XmlToXSR" class="org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XmlToXMLStreamReader" doc:name="XMLTOORACLE">**

        </custom-transformer>

         <component doc:name="Java">
              <spring-object bean="OracleCDMMapper"/>
        </component>


   -->      
        <logger message ="I am Complete "  level="INFO" doc:name ="LoggerMurali" />


    </flow>


</mule>
```

Here is the Javacode:

```
Spring Bean 
public class OracleCDMMapper implements Callable {

     private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OracleCDMMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MuleMessage muleMessage = eventContext.getMessage();

        logger.info("In the Spring Component");

        logger.info(muleMessage.getPayload().getClass().toString());


        **javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader xsr =  (XMLStreamReader) muleMessage.getPayload(javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader.class);**
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Are you certain you're getting an instance of XMLUtils? There are a couple of places in the source code that I see it returning an anonymous inner class that does indeed implement XMLStreamReader.  This would appear as something like XMLUtils$2 if you use toStriing() on the Class.  Maybe also try logging the getClass().getName() or getFullName().

Answer (score 1):

I've verified and you are right, in the code the supposed returning class should be a `DelegateXMLStreamReader` class that implements `XMLStreamReader`, but the returned class is an anonymous inner class of `XMLUtils` that at runtime cannot be casted to any Stream like class. It seems to be a defect.

If you really need the control of the xml stream, you could use a custom java component:

```
 <component class="com.foo.CustomJavaComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
```

.

```
public class CustomJavaComponent implements Callable{

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        MuleMessage muleMessage = eventContext.getMessage();

        FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream)muleMessage.getPayload();
        //Do something with this stream

        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

And get the input stream to do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the update , I am moving to a custom component